# Display XML data in Excel

Tags: xml, oracle, excel, oracle-apex

I have table (table1) with clob field (field1).
Content of field1 is xml data.
When I save data from field1 (copy/paste) in new file(e.g. D:\test1.xml) I can opet that file in Excel.

I need to open this data (table1.field1) in Excel from Apex 4 application.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a stored procedure that will serve up the file with the correct MIME type so that a browser knows it must be opened in Excel (usually `application/excel`).

The full instructions for how to do this are in the Apex documentation here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14373_01/appdev.32/e13363/up_dn_files.htm#CIHDDJGF